# touchIDLockout deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compilation, touch-id

When compiling my Application with Xcode 9 for IOS11 I get the following warnings:

```
warning: 'touchIDLockout' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryLockout

warning: 'touchIDNotEnrolled' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled

warning: 'touchIDNotAvailable' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable
```

I'm using touchID but I'm not using touchIdLockout...cste and the touchID is working correctly.

How can I remove these warnings?

---

#### Edit (not by the original author):

I tracked this down to a single cause. It's enough to reference `LAError` from the LocalAuthentication framework in my code to make these warnings appear.

Steps to reproduce (tried in Xcode 9.2):

1. Create a new iOS app (Single View template). Note the iOS Deployment Target is set to iOS 11.2.
2. Add these lines to `AppDelegate.swift`:

   ```
   import LocalAuthentication
   ```

   And a single line in `appDidFinishLaunching`:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       let _: LAError? = nil
       return true
   }
   ```
3. Build the app.

The `let _: LAError? = nil` line is enough to make the three warnings appear. The warnings are not associated with any particular line of code, though. They appear in the build log without any file/line reference:

```
<unknown>:0: warning: 'touchIDLockout' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryLockout
<unknown>:0: warning: 'touchIDNotEnrolled' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled
<unknown>:0: warning: 'touchIDNotAvailable' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable
```

**Here's a screenshot:** [Screenshot of the warnings in Xcode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/88yaevxxikj80ow/LocalAuthenticationWarnings-screenshot.png?dl=0)

**And a sample project:** [Sample project for download (Xcode 9.2)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x08woyornmpmq9y/LocalAuthenticationWarnings.zip?dl=0)

For reference, I reported this to Apple. Radar #36028653.

Comment: @Ole: Can you reproduce the *"deprecation warnings even if you don't use the touchID... identifiers"* issue?

Comment: @MartinR I added more info to the question (sorry to sebastien for hijacking this).

Comment: Still occurring with Xcode 10 GM.

Answer (score 25):

**Short answer:** It looks like a compiler bug to me, caused
by the import of a C enumeration which defines multiple constants
with the same value.

**Long answer:** Unfortunately I do not have a solution how to avoid the deprecation
warning, only a possible explanation what causes it.

The `LAError` codes are defined as a C enumeration in 
`<LAError.h>` in the LocalAuthentication framework. Here is an
extract of that definition:

```
// Error codes
#define kLAErrorAuthenticationFailed                       -1
#define kLAErrorUserCancel                                 -2
// ...
#define kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable                        -6
#define kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled                         -7
#define kLAErrorTouchIDLockout                             -8
// ...
#define kLAErrorBiometryNotAvailable                        kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable
#define kLAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled                         kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled
#define kLAErrorBiometryLockout                             kLAErrorTouchIDLockout

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, LAError)
{
    LAErrorAuthenticationFailed = kLAErrorAuthenticationFailed,
    LAErrorUserCancel = kLAErrorUserCancel,
    // ...
    LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable,
    LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled,
    LAErrorTouchIDLockout NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_11, 10_13, 9_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryLockout")
    __WATCHOS_DEPRECATED(3.0, 4.0, "use LAErrorBiometryLockout") __TVOS_DEPRECATED(10.0, 11.0, "use LAErrorBiometryLockout") = kLAErrorTouchIDLockout,
    // ...
    LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_13, 11_0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(4.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(11.0) = kLAErrorBiometryNotAvailable,
    LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_13, 11_0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(4.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(11.0) = kLAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled,
    LAErrorBiometryLockout NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_13, 11_0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(4.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(11.0) = kLAErrorBiometryLockout,
    // ...
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(10.0);
```

One can see that "old" (deprecated) and the "new" error codes use
the same values. For example, both  `LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable` and `LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable` are defined as `-6`.

That is perfectly valid in C, but the raw values of a Swift `enum` must
be mutually distinct. Apparently the Swift importer solves that by
mapping the new/duplicate cases to static variables.

Here is an extract of the Swift mapping:

```
public struct LAError {

    public init(_nsError: NSError)
    public static var _nsErrorDomain: String { get }


    public enum Code : Int {
        case authenticationFailed
        case userCancel
        // ...
        @available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 11.0, message: "use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable")
        case touchIDNotAvailable
        @available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 11.0, message: "use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled")
        case touchIDNotEnrolled
        @available(iOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 11.0, message: "use LAErrorBiometryLockout")
        case touchIDLockout
        // ...
        @available(iOS 11.0, *)
        public static var biometryNotAvailable: LAError.Code { get }
        @available(iOS 11.0, *)
        public static var biometryNotEnrolled: LAError.Code { get }
        @available(iOS 11.0, *)
        public static var biometryLockout: LAError.Code { get }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

And this seems to be the cause for the deprecation warnings, and
also for the problem reported on the swift-users mailing list

- [[swift-users] Handle deprecated enum cases from a library](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20171030/006545.html)

that it is impossible to write an exhaustive and warning-free
switch statement for `LAError`.

---

To prove my conjecture, I have reproduced the problem with a custom
enumeration: Add the following definition to the bridging header
file of an macOS 10.13 or iOS 11 project:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum)
{
    MyEnumA = 1,
    MyEnumB = 2,
    MyEnumC NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use MyEnumNewC") = 3,

    MyEnumNewC NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_13, 11_0) = 3,
};
```

This is imported to Swift as

```
 public enum MyEnum : Int {
    case A
    case B
    @available(OSX, introduced: 10_10, deprecated: 10_13, message: "use MyEnumNewC")
    case C

    @available(OSX 10_13, *)
    public static var newC: MyEnum { get }
 }
```

with 3 cases for the first (distinct) enum values, and a static
property for the duplicate value.

And indeed, any use of `MyEnum` triggers a deprecation warning:

```
// main.swift:
print(MyEnum.A) // Or: let _: MyEnum? = nil

// Build log:
// <unknown>:0: warning: 'C' was deprecated in OS X 10.13: use MyEnumNewC
```

In addition, it is not possible to use the new enum value in a
switch statement:

```
func foo(err: MyEnum) {
    switch err {
    case .A:
        print("A")
    case .B:
        print("B")
    case .newC:
        print("C")
    }
}

// Build log:
// main.swift:12:9: error: switch must be exhaustive
// <unknown>:0: warning: 'C' was deprecated in OS X 10.13: use MyEnumNewC
```

even if the compiler (apparently) knows that these cases are exhaustive:

```
func foo(err: MyEnum) {
    switch err { // Switch must be exhaustive
    case .A:
        print("A")
    case .B:
        print("B")
    case .newC:
        print("C")
    default:
        print("default")
    }
}

// Build log:
// <unknown>:0: warning: 'C' was deprecated in OS X 10.13: use MyEnumNewC
// main.swift:19:9: warning: default will never be executed
```

This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I believe you're right.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive report. Is there a clang/llvm issue somewhere that you can track?

Comment: @skagedal: None that I know of. It has been discussed in the Swift forums (https://forums.swift.org/t/handle-deprecated-enum-cases-from-a-library/6952), but I cannot find a corresponding issue at https://bugs.swift.org, so apparently nobody reported it so far.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I commented to at least bump it on the forums.

Comment: Ah, there is a Swift bug from Ole. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6637

Answer (score 7):

Yes, these are new warnings which are present as Apple moves to iOS 11 and FaceID. Most likely, you are checking to see if the biometric hardware is not locked out, has enrolled fingerprints, and the device has the supporting hardware.

Here an example set up:

```
import LocalAuthentication

...

var authContext = LAContext()
var biometricsError: NSError?
authContext?.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &biometricsError)
```

Up to iOS 10, one would run checks like this:

```
if biometricsError?.code == LAError.touchIDNotAvailable.rawValue {
  // No hardware
}

if biometricsError?.code == LAError.touchIDNotEnrolled.rawValue {
  // No fingerprints
}

if biometricsError?.code == LAError.touchIDLockout.rawValue {
  // Locked out
}
```

**Note:** iOS 11 introduced a slight variant of the above code. Instead of using `LAError.touchID` for each error property, they introduced `LAError.biometry`. Therefore you would have: `biometryNotAvailable`, `biometryNotEnrolled`, and `biometryLockout`.

Apple seems to prefer this approach, instead:

```
if biometricsError?.code == Int(kLAErrorBiometryNotAvailable) {
  // No hardware
}

if biometricsError?.code == Int(kLAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled) {
  // No fingerprints
}

if biometricsError?.code == Int(kLAErrorBiometryLockout) {
  // Locked out
}
```

This method gets rid of Xcode's warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it doesn't remove the warning because I'm not using LAError.touchIDNotAvailable, LAError.touchIDNotEnrolled or LAError.touchIDLockout.
I agree these constants are obsolete in IOS11 but I'm not using them!

Comment: It should be noted that this is not an approach that Apple seems to prefer, but a confirmed compiler bug – see the above answer, The workaround of using the kLAError constants _does_ work though. But with a caveat. I'll add my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

As has been noted, this is a bug in the compiler. The Swift team are aware and you might want to go and [vote for the bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6637).  At the same time, add a watch on it so that you can remove the following workaround when it has been fixed.

What you need to do in order to not get the warnings is: **do not mention `LAError`**. Think of `LAError` as Voldemort.

Instead, use Objective-C style error checking.  All `Error` enums map to an `NSError`, which are built up from a domain and a code.  The constants to compare these with are also exported to Swift.  They can be named without warnings.  So your code might look a little (hopefully, very little) like this.

```swift
let context = LAContext()
let text = "Authenticate, please!"
context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: text) { (success, error) in
    if success {
        print("")
    } else {
        guard let error = error else {
            return print("Should not happen according to the docs!")
        }
        let nsError = error as NSError
        switch nsError.domain {
        case kLAErrorDomain:
            switch nsError.code {
            case Int(kLAErrorUserCancel):
                print("User cancelled.")
            case Int(kLAErrorBiometryLockout):
                print("Biometry lockout.")
            default:
                print("Unhandled error.")
            }
        default:
            print("Unhandled error domain. Probably will not happen.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Yes, other, existing answers showed same technique but none really brought it all together and did not mention to check for the domain so I thought I'd write this up.)

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this for a very long time. Oliver's answer led me to a solution that worked for me, but just in case there are others that are still having this issue - it seems that ANY reference to the old LAError values will produce the warnings listed above.

For example, this simple code produces the warnings. Remove ALL reference to the old codes and use Oliver's approach.

```
func evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForLA(errorCode: Int) -> String {
    var message = ""

    switch errorCode {
    case LAError.authenticationFailed.rawValue:
        message = "The user failed to provide valid credentials"
    default:
        message = "Can't use any version of old LAError"
    }

    return message
}//evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForLA
```

In fact, it can be even simpler. Try this:

```
func evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForBiometricsError(biometricsError: Int) -> String {

    var message = "I would normally leave this blank"

    if biometricsError == kLAErrorBiometryNotAvailable {
        message = "Biometrics are not available on this device"
    }//if not avail

    if biometricsError == kLAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled {
        message = "Biometrics are not enrolled on this device"
    }//if not enrolled

    if biometricsError == kLAErrorBiometryLockout {
        message = "Biometrics are locked out on this device"
    }//if locked out

    return message

}//evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForBiometricsError
```