# Swift enum cannot assign default raw value

Tags: swift

Sample code:

```
enum BestLetters {
    case A
    case B
    case C
    case Default = B
}
```

The error in the `Default` case: **Raw value for enum case must be a literal**

My understanding is that enum raw values are limited to certain types (Ints, Strings, Booleans, etc). Obviously `BestLetters` isn't  one of those types and the compiler is complaining.

How can I set the `Default` type's raw value to one of the other "letters"? If gives any context, the reason for this odd syntax is that I am trying to imitate something I saw in obj-c.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How will this be used? Might help to show the Objective-C code. Also add an example of how you want to use this default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (Objective-)C an enumeration defines a set of named integer constants, and those need not be distinct:

```
enum {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 99,
    Default = B
};
```

The cases of a Swift `enum` represent mutually distinct values, and their raw values – if assigned – must be unique:

```
enum BestLetters: Int {
    case a = 1
    case b
    case c
    case `default` = 2 // Error: Raw value for enum case is not unique
}
```

On the other hand, enumerations in Swift are first-class types, so that you can define a static property for that purpose:

```
enum BestLetters {
    case a
    case b
    case c
    static let `default` = BestLetters.b
}
```

(This is also how Swift imports C enumerations with duplicate values, compare [touchIDLockout deprecated in iOS 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455424/touchidlockout-deprecated-in-ios-11-0/47802525#47802525).)

Comment: Thank you! Why the backticks around default?

Comment: @GranolaGuy: Because “default” is a reserved word in Swift, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41503740/1187415. If you rename it to “defaultLetter” then the backticks are not needed.

Comment: This is a good read on enum inits


  [1]: https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/03/13/mutable-self/